# How to use Proxy properly?

Tags: haskell

Why this code doesn't work?

```
class Foo a where 
    foo :: Proxy a -> Int

bar :: Foo a => a -> Int
bar _ = foo (Proxy :: Proxy a)
```

It fails to compile with the message:

```
Could not deduce (Foo a0) arising from a use of `foo'
from the context (Foo a)
  bound by the type signature for bar :: Foo a => a -> Int
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
In the expression: foo (Proxy :: Proxy a)
In an equation for `bar': bar _ = foo (Proxy :: Proxy a)
```

I tried it with and without ScopedTypeVariables extension

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need `ScopedTypeVariables` *and* `forall` introduction to [get a scoped type variable:](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables)

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

bar :: forall a. Foo a => a -> Int
bar _ = foo (Proxy :: Proxy a)
```